# JQuery - Object doesn't support this property or method for IE 7,8,9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, compiler-errors

I'm currently using JQuery to trigger an event when a clicked link with a URL that doesn't contain 'out'. I get a 'Object doesnt support' error on IE 7,8 and 9.

```
$('a:not([href*="out"]').click(function(e){
    alert("Boo");
});
```

Comment: Is that a typo, or is your code actually missing the closing bracket for the `:not()` selector?

Comment: Thanks winterblood. The code was missing the closing bracket.